# Unable to merge account with a draft submission into another account

Tags: guidewire

While merging an Account with a Submission in Draft status into another Account,  I get the below error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Slice date Sat Aug 17 00:01:00 EDT 2019 outside of range [Sat Aug 17 00:01:00 EDT 2019 - Sat Aug 17 00:01:00 EDT 2019] for bean of type PolicyLocation  at com.guidewire.pl.system.entity.proxy.EffDatedBaseProxy.getSliceUntyped(EffDatedBaseProxy.java:586)  at com.guidewire.pl.system.entity.proxy.EffDatedBeanProxy.getSliceUntyped(EffDatedBeanProxy.java:999)  at com.guidewire.pl.system.entity.proxy.EffDatedBeanProxy.getSliceUntyped(EffDatedBeanProxy.java:49)  at entity.PolicyLocation.getSliceUntyped(PolicyLocation.java:939)  at entity.PolicyLocation.getSlice(PolicyLocation.java:913)`

Comment: Can you add the product version you are using (GCP ski release or on-prem version)? Does the account you are trying to merge into another account also have other bound policy transactions? In a lower environment, have you tried withdrawing the draft submission and then merging the accounts? Add some more details and I'll try to give a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the error, follow these steps:

1. Quote/withdraw the Submission in the Account to be consumed in the Merge
2. Retry the Merge process

This should fix the error if you're on PolicyCenter 9.x, 10.x, or 2020.05 (Aspen).

Answer (score 0):

seems like the PolicyLocation object of outside the policy effective date range.
modify your PolicyLocation to

var pl = your_PolicyLocation_Obj.getSlice(pl.Branch.**POL_EffDate**)